# Inserting data from <option> to Database in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, frameworks

Trying to insert a data using Option form in CRUD app. but its says

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'site_category' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `company` (`site_category`, `category_rest`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ( , , 1, 2017-09-01 08:30:09, 2017-09-01 08:30:09))

View

```
                      {!! Form::open(['action' => 'CompanyController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="siteCategory">Choose your website category</label><br>
                            <select class="custom-select" id="siteCategory">
                                  <option name="test1" value="test1">Option 1</option>
                                  <option name="test2" value="test2">Option 2</option>
                                  <option name="test3" value="test3">Option 3</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="restrictCategory">Choose your website categories restrictions</label><br>
                            <select class="custom-select" id="restrictCategory" multiple>
                                  <option name="test4" value="test4">Option 1</option>
                                  <option name="test5" value="test5">Option 2</option>
                                  <option name="test6" value="test6">Option 3</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Company</button>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $company = new Company;
    $company->site_category = $request->input('test1');
    $company->site_category = $request->input('test2');
    $company->site_category = $request->input('test3');
    $company->category_rest= $request->input('test4');
    $company->category_rest= $request->input('test5');
    $company->category_rest= $request->input('test6');
    $company->user_id = auth()->user()->id; //sync with user
    $company->save();

    return redirect('/dashboard/company');
}
```

I guess something wrong in my action controller, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must name your elements, they represent the keys in the "$request" associative array.

```
<select class="custom-select" id="siteCategory" name="siteCategory">
```

and

```
<select class="custom-select" id="restrictCategory" name="restrictCategory[]" multiple> // set name attribute to an array to get all the selected choices
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $company = new Company;
    $company->site_category = $request->input('siteCategory');
    $company->category_rest= implode(',', $request->input('restrictCategory')); // store it as string separated by commas
    $company->user_id = auth()->user()->id; //sync with user
    $company->save();

    return redirect('/dashboard/company');
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works, thanks for a help
Btw when I choose multiply rows it saves only one value.
Is it possible to save multiply?

Comment: Yes, you can. I edit my answer with an example, which stores the data as a string separated by commas.

Comment: Thank you mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your actual controller can be safely replaced with the code below cus u r overwritting the site_category and category_rest attributes setted on the previous lines.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $company = new Company;
    $company->site_category = $request->input('test3');
    $company->category_rest= $request->input('test6');
    $company->user_id = auth()->user()->id; //sync with user
    $company->save();

    return redirect('/dashboard/company');
}
```

Second, you must name your elements, they represent the keys in the "$request" associative array.

```
<select class="custom-select" id="siteCategory" name="siteCategory">
<select class="custom-select" id="restrictCategory" name="restrictCategory[]" multiple> // set name attribute to an array to get all the selected choices
```

So, folowing the first step, your controller will look like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $company = new Company;
    $company->site_category = $request->input('siteCategory');
    $company->category_rest= implode(',', $request->input('restrictCategory')); // store it as string separated by commas
    $company->user_id = auth()->user()->id; //sync with user
    $company->save();

    return redirect('/dashboard/company');
}
```